# Будет ли письмо доставлено, если отправитель письма ipv6 smtp, а получатель -  ipv4?

Tags: postfix, smtp, linux

Планируется  перевести почтовый сервер Postfix на ipv6.

Будут ли проблемы у ipv6 сервера с доставкой на почтовые сервера ipv4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наоборот (с 4 в 6) - бывают нюансы, с 6 в 4 - обычно все ок. 6 воспринимает 4ку, как просто диаппазон адресов, а 4ка видит шлюз.

Comment: спасибо, понял.